# Is there a way of making iPhoto's Photo Stream one-way sharing?

Tags: photos.app

Is there a way of making iPhoto's *Photo Stream* one-way sharing? As I don't want all the pictures I download from my regular camera on iPhoto to be shared with my iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Under **iPhoto / Preferences / Photo Stream** you can disable *Automatic Upload*. When turned off, you'll have to manually select which photos will be shared on the Photo Stream.

[image]

There are several ways of manually adding photos to the photo stream. After selecting the photos you want to share just:

- Click the **Share** button in the toolbar, choose *Photo Stream* from the pop-up menu, and click *My Photo Stream*.
- Click the **Add To** button in the toolbar, choose *Photo Stream* from the pop-up menu, and click *My Photo Stream*.
- Choose **Share / Photo Stream**, and click *My Photo Stream*.